# ActiveRecord Query to get a SUM across tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: quotes
#
#  id                      :integer          not null, primary key
#  bound_rate_id           :integer
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  #snip
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: rates
#
#  id                             :integer          not null, primary key
#  quoted_premium                 :integer
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  #snip
end
```

I want to create a query that would calculate the same thing as this loop:

```
sum = 0
for quote in Quote.all
  rate = Rate.find(quote.bound_rate_id)
  sum += rate.quoted_premium
end
```

How would I do this using ActiveRecord's query interface? (I am using Rails 4.)

---

EDIT: I already have `ActiveRecord` instances from previous queries over `Quote`, so I would prefer to have my query start from the `quotes` table and join to the `rates` table, not the other way around. Like this:

```
some_quotes = Quote.where(:some_other_property, my_param);
sum_of_rates = some_quotes.?????
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out

```
sum = Rate.where(:id => Quote.pluck(:bound_rate_id).compact).sum(:quoted_premium)
```

After adding relations try this out

```
 sum = Quote.joins(:rate).sum('rates.quoted_premium') # it will get sum of all query's   quoted_premium
```

To get sum of some specific add where clause

```
 sum = Quote.joins(:rate).where(:bound_rate_id => [list of Rate ids]).sum('rates.quoted_premium')
```

If you get a `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'rates.bound_rate_id' in 'on clause'` error, specify how ActiveRecord should put together the join

```
sum = Quote.joins('INNER JOIN rates ON quotes.bound_rate_id = rates.id').sum('rates.quoted_premium')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately (and I didn't make this clear in my question), I already have `ActiveRecord` instances from queries to my `quotes` table, so I would rather have my query start from the `quotes` table and join to the `rates` table.

Comment: @Kevin state the relation between two models.

Comment: I looked at the models. Neither of them have `belongs_to`, `has_many`, or `belongs_to_and_has_many` relationships explicitly defined that programmatically relate them. I think we're "manually" setting up a relationship where every `Quote` has 1 or 0 `Rate`s, and each `Rate` belongs to a single `Quote`.

Comment: They're also related indirectly through a third table. I still think I want to directly join the `quotes` and `rates` tables through `Quote#bound_rate_id`, though, because we use the third table for a different piece of functionality than what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Kevin then you should add activerecord relationships like 'has_one :rate, foreign_key: 'bound_rate_id'' in Quote model, and 'belongs_to :quote, foreign_key: 'bound_rate_id'' for using ActiveRecord's query interface

Comment: Once I've made that change, how do I write my query? (I'm pretty new to Rails.)